# Yii2 how to pass variable from view and send to another source

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2

all

My point is. 
I need to create a custom report by passing a value from $valiable in view -> controller

my question is how to pass value from $valiable

now I can get value from another system by **fix value in $valiable in controller.php**

***but I need to pass $valiable from view.php that selected after submit button.***

something like this

[image]

here my code

index.php

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
           <label class="control-label"> field1 </label>
             <?php echo Select2::widget([
                'name' => 'field1',
                'data' =>  Report::itemAlias('field1'),
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Select Cost Center...',
                ],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true,],
                ]); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
           <label class="control-label"> field2 </label>
             <?php echo Select2::widget([
                'name' => 'field2',
                'data' => Report::itemAlias('field2'),
                'options' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Select Fund Center...',
                ],
                    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true,],
                ]); ?>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
           <?= Html::submitButton('process', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning ']) ?>  
        </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

in ReportController.php

```
public function actionIndex ()
        {
            $array = [];  // for array result 
            $field1 =  '';  // if fix value $field1 =  'a'; can pass a to $result
            $field2 =  '';  // if fix value $field2 =  'b'; can pass b to  $result

                 if (Yii::$app->request->isPost)  
             {
                $FISTL =  $_POST['field1'];  // view ~field1
                $FIPEX =  $_POST['field2'];  // view ~field2
             }

        if($field1 !== '' && $field1 !== ''){    *// add if condition for get variable*
            $connection = Yii::$app->sconnection->connectionToAnotherSystem(); // connection to another system
            $result = $connection->getValue([     
                'field1' => $field1,    // if fix value $field1 =  'a'; can pass a to $result
                'field2' => $field2,    // if fix value $field2 =  'b'; can pass b to  $result
            ]);
            $array = array(['value' =>$result]);//return value from another system 

            } $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $array,
            ]);
            return $this->render('index',
                [
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, // true data
                ]);
        }
```

**EDIT : i got what I want. in controller.php add if condition.**

Comment: not clear what you are asking are these 2 different applications that you want to communicate between, why not use curl to send request and get the response

Comment: curl not an option sir,
I just wanna retrieve data from another application by select $variable from Yii2 Application.

Comment: i got what i want already update question. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it at all

But suposing you have the other system's response in $result, it looks like an array; then you are asigning an array in the variable $array that have an assosiative value called 'value'.
The way to get the field1 value is

```
$array['value']['field1']
```

You should have a GridView like this in your view php file

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'columns' => [
    ...
    'value.field1',
    'value.field2',
    ...
  ],
]); ?>
```

That should works